# Rails Tutorial NoMethodError in Users#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm following along with the Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. We just created a Users database (this first part of "demo_app"), but when I start the server and navigate to the new users page I get the following error:

```
    NoMethodError in Users#index
```

and the application trace:

```
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2922823401409246272_70101530338460'
    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

I really have no idea how to decipher these error messages but here is my users_controller file:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   # GET /users
   # GET /users.json
   def index
      @users = User.all

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
   end
end
....
 ....
```

Line 7 is the `respond_to do |format|` line. Any thoughts? Complete newbie to Ruby and Rails (figured I'd learn Ruby on the fly).

P.s. it's not a syntax error. I know that much.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't you forgot one `end`?

```
def index
   @users = User.all

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is in not closing out the `respond_to do |format|` block. Should be:

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
```

Comment: I have not. I just didn't include it in the summary (there are other methods below `index`, I excluded them for the sake of brevity)

Comment: @MikeB Are you sure? After your edit, the question still contains syntax error. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare your code with mine, but I am not sure where you are in the tut. In chapter 2, we built a demo app, but in my Users.controller there is no 'respond_to … block.
In that case,  you should probably close the def index with end, but I am not sure where your respond_to block should go in that case. 
In chapter 4, where there IS a respond_to block, I don't have an index-method in my Users.controller

So, could you tell what chapter you are working in? And maybe post the complete Users.controller file?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `config/routes.rb` file contain a line declaring that your urls /users/* should dispatch to your UsersController?

If the line doesn't exist, you should add in `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :users
```